# Add total to column where row header meets criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies beforehand for this, I'm very new to VBA and I'm sure this is simple coding that I'm struggling with.

Based on a user defined number of months (just entered into the ssheet) I have a row of column headings giving the month number and the heading "Total" after the last month.

i.e. User says 12 months, cell A2 = "Jan-15" and M2 = "Total".

Underneath the headings the user then adds some sales data.

What I need to do is use VBA to add a total to the end of each of the rows of data where the header = "total".

I was thinking an If Then makes sense but I'm struggling with how to get the macro to put the formula in the correct cell and then have the formula look at the variable range. This is the best I've come up with so far (please don't laugh!)

```
Sub Add_total()
Dim criteria As String
criteria = Range("A:A").Value
If criteria = "Total" Then
Range("12:12").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=sum($c12:c12)"
End If
End Sub
```

What I'd like is, for example, where M2 = "Total", then C12 = sum(c1:L12)

I realise the easiest way would be to just get the user to add the total themselves or have a total column far away to the left of the sheet but this is going across the business and needs to restrict manual input/guarantee accuracy of the calcs.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply put in cell `M3` the function `=sum(A3:L3)` and copy downwards?

If you need it in VBA anyway should this work:

```
Sub testsum()
i = 3 'start in cell3
While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))
Cells(i, 13) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range((Cells(i, 1)), (Cells(i, 12))))
i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Really sorry about the editing on this, for some reason I can't add a line... Thanks very much for that - not quite what I needed but you pointed me in the direction. Went for the following in the end: 'Sub Total() Set Find_total = Range("6:6").Find("Total", LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByColumns) Set Revenue_total = Find_total.Offset(rowoffset:=3, columnoffset:=-1) Set Revenue_cell = Find_total.Offset(rowoffset:=3, columnoffset:=0) Revenue_cell = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range((Cells(9, 2)), Revenue_total)) End Sub'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for that - not quite what I needed but you pointed me in the direction. Went for the following in the end:

```
Sub Total() Set Find_total = Range("6:6").Find("Total",_
LookIn:=xlValues,searchorder:=xlByColumns) 
Set Revenue_total = Find_total.Offset(rowoffset:=3, columnoffset:=-1) 
Set Revenue_cell = Find_total.Offset(rowoffset:=3, columnoffset:=0)
Revenue_cell = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range((Cells(9, 2)), Revenue_total)) 
End Sub
```

Thanks again